# Stuck at selecting the path for webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use the selenium library for web scraping but I have encountered two problems.

Firstly, I am using Chromer version 119 and I didn't find the webdriver for this. I then randomly downloaded the 114 version driver and tried to locate the path.
Secondly, when I copied the path of the web driver and put it in the program it showed the error `'(Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape'`.
I also searched about this problem but didn't find the solution yet.

I didn't find any helpful material for this problem. Therefore, seeking a solution and posting here the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

download chrome driver 119 from below link
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Comment: I downloaded the webdriver but I am still getting the same error of '(Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape'. Please suggest what to do now.
I am also attaching the code below.
from selenium import webdriver
website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'
path = """C:\Users\beenco\Downloads\chromedriver"""
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website)

Comment: put r before your string... or use "/" instead of "\" in path. (and maybe ditch the triple quotation marks)  Python is trying to escape "\U" as a unicode begin... then it gets weird.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there might be an issue with how the chromedriver path is set up.

In the context of specifying the path to a WebDriver in Selenium, it's common to use the double backslashes or a raw string to avoid any potential issues with escape characters. For example:

```
"C:\\Users\\beenco\\Downloads\\chromedriver"
```

Alternatively:

```
path_with_raw_string = r"C:\\Users\\beenco\\Downloads\\chromedriver"
```

Or this way:

```
 "C:/Users/beenco/Downloads/chromedriver"
```

The reason for using double slashes or backslashes is related to how these characters are interpreted in string literals in programming languages. In many programming languages, a single backslash is used as an escape character. For instance, "\n" represents a newline character, "\t" represents a tab character, and so on.

By using double slashes or backslashes, you are escaping the escape character itself. For file paths in Windows, backslashes are used to separate directories, and if you use a single backslash in a string literal, it may be treated as an escape character. Therefore, to represent a literal backslash in a file path, you use **two backslashes** to escape the first one.

This is a common practice in various programming languages when dealing with file paths on Windows systems. It's not specific to Selenium but rather a general convention for representing file paths in string literals in many programming languages.