# My Python script throws an error when I want to initialize Chrome Driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am using Windows 8.1. I have installed python 3.12.0 and PowerShell 7.3.9. I am using VSCode for coding and the shell is in it.

Here is my code-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import selenium


chrome_driver_path = "D:\\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chrome_service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
driver.get('https://studio.youtube.com/channel/UC57gBc9mbUVAXRdkOfPKaYw/videos/upload')
```

Some Important Information-

Chrome Version- 109.0.5414.169
Chrome WebDriver Version- 109.0.5414.74
Selenium Version- 4.15.2
PowerShell 7.3.9
Python- 3.12.0

Please help me. I am new in Python.
Thanks in advance.

It Shows-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Downloads\upload.py", line 54, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Sarker Ayon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x00D06643]
        (No symbol) [0x00C9BE21]
        (No symbol) [0x00B9DA9D]
        (No symbol) [0x00BBD95D]
        (No symbol) [0x00BBA899]
        (No symbol) [0x00BF6917]
        (No symbol) [0x00BF655C]
        (No symbol) [0x00BEFB76]
        (No symbol) [0x00BC49C1]
        (No symbol) [0x00BC5E5D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F7A142+2497106]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FA85D3+2686691]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00FABB9C+2700460]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DB3B10+635936]
        (No symbol) [0x00CA4A1F]
        (No symbol) [0x00CAA418]
        (No symbol) [0x00CAA505]
        (No symbol) [0x00CB508B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x773B6A24+36]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x776FA9FF+143]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x776FA9CA+90]
```

Comment: update your chromedriver and check if it works [here's a link](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you're facing is a **WebDriverException**, signaling an issue in creating the Chrome process during the initialization of ChromeDriver with Selenium.
There could be several reasons for this issue:

1. ChromeDriver Version Mismatch
2. Incorrect ChromeDriver Path
3. Chrome Browser Version

If the provided code accurately reflects the implementation in your program, it suggests that the issue may be related to the **ChromeDriver path**.

Indeed, the correct and professional way to provide the ChromeDriver path is to use either a **raw string** or **double backslashes** to ensure proper handling of the file path.

```
chrome_driver_path = r"D:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
# or
chrome_driver_path = "D:\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
```

For further insights into the specification of executable paths, I recommend referring to the following link:
[Stuck at selecting the path for webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77464070/stuck-at-selecting-the-path-for-webdriver/77611530#77611530)

In a similar manner, the binary location should be specified using the correct format like the above.

and you should also change the way you have provided the service class:

```
chrome_service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)
```

This would result in an error because the correct syntax is `Service(chrome_driver_path)` without the webdriver.chrome prefix. The webdriver.chrome prefix is not needed when working with the Service class.

Certainly, please try the provided code.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import selenium

# Corrected file paths
chrome_driver_path = r"drivers/chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
chrome_service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
driver.get("https://studio.youtube.com/channel/UC57gBc9mbUVAXRdkOfPKaYw/videos/upload")
```

I encourage you to test the provided code, and kindly inform me of its effectiveness. If any errors persist, please do not hesitate to communicate them, and I will gladly assist further.